# Is it possible to use xdmp:save with REST?

Tags: rest, curl, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm attempting to copy a large document to the file system from a MarkLogic database. I'd like to do it with REST and maybe `xdmp:save`. However, I haven't been able to find any info on how to do this. Here is what I have:

```
curl -s --anyauth --user admin:admin -X GET -i -d "xdmp:save('/my/workspace/uris/LargeDoc.xml', fn:doc('/Collection/SomeDatabase/LargeDoc.xml'))" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" "http://localhost:8000/v1/eval?database=SomeDatabase"
```

Is this possible? 
I am able to do the `xdmp:save('/my/workspace/uris/LargeDoc.xml', fn:doc('/Collection/SomeDatabase/LargeDoc.xml'))` in the qconsole with the correct database selected. However, I'd like to create a script or tool to do this task.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What issues are you having? Keep in mind that `xdmp:save` tells the **server** to save a file to the path on it's filesystem. If you want to download the file to the client invoking the script, then retrieve it with `http://localhost:8000/v1/documents?uri=/Collection/SomeDatabase/LargeDoc.xml&database=SomeDatabase` and save the response wherever you want to.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to download the document using the REST API, request it from the [/v1/documents (GET)](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents) endpoint.

For example, using curl, you can save the response to a local file using the **[`-o`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o)** option:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X GET --create-dirs 
  -o /Collection/SomeDatabase/LargeDoc.xml 
  "http://localhost:8000/v1/documents?uri=/Collection/SomeDatabase/LargeDoc.xml&database=SomeDatabase"
```